# Pandas: how to get index value of non-unique index

Tags: pandas, datetime, indexing, pandas-resample

I have a data frame with a date time index where index values are non unique (see last two index values).

I would like to get the next valid index value given a time delta of +5 seconds from the first index value. In the case below, the first index value = '2018-12-03 08:00:00.410' and adding 5 seconds to that would result in '2018-12-03 08:00:05.410'. The next valid index value would be '2018-12-03 08:00:08.680'.

```
                                  ID       PRICE 
DATETIME                                             
2018-12-03 08:00:00.410            1       3229.0
2018-12-03 08:00:00.550            1       3229.0
2018-12-03 08:00:00.630            1       3229.0
2018-12-03 08:00:08.680            1       3230.0
2018-12-03 08:00:08.680            1       3230.0
```

I tried to apply

```
idx = df.index[df.index.get_loc('2018-12-03 08:00:05.410', method='bfill')]
```

but I get `Exception has occurred: InvalidIndexError Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

How can I get the index value knowing it is non-unique?

Comment: `df.index[df.index >= (df.index[0] + pd.Timedelta(seconds=5))][0]` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.index[df.index.duplicated()].tolist()
```